# How to fix a QFocusEvent behavior

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyside2

I'm making a widget to access and modify QGraphicsRectItem
properties(scale, rotation, etc.). The main idea is to show a widget on clicking on an item. When you click on another item, this widget should be deleted and replaced by another(showing properties of another item.)

I've implemented this using **QFocusEvent** and unfortunately, it gives me a **SIGSEGV** error. I fully understand why it happens but can`t make out how to do it in another way.

Here's a python sketch:

```py
from PySide2 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
import sys, shiboken2


class graphicsView(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self, scene, parent=None):
        super(graphicsView, self).__init__(parent)
        self.scene = scene

        self.setScene(self.scene)

    def wheelEvent(self, event):
        factor = 1.41 ** (-event.delta() / 240)
        self.scale(factor, factor)

class boxItem(QtWidgets.QGraphicsRectItem):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(boxItem, self).__init__()

        self.setFlags(QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable
                      | QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable
                      | QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsFocusable)

        self.rect = QtCore.QRectF(0, 0, 200, 200)
        self.setRect(self.rect)

        self.parent = parent


    def focusInEvent(self, event:QtGui.QFocusEvent):
        self.pBox = propBox()
        self.parent.layout.addWidget(self.pBox)
        self.pBox.r_box.setValue(self.rotation())
        self.pBox.r_box.valueChanged.connect(self.setRotationAngle)


    def focusOutEvent(self, event:QtGui.QFocusEvent):
        # Here's a shiboken(equivalent to sip in PyQt) deletes c++ object and a python wrapper
        # It works as expected but because of focusOutEvent it deletes the widget when i click on it
        # There's when the error appears.

        self.parent.layout.removeWidget(self.pBox)
        shiboken2.delete(self.pBox)

    def setRotationAngle(self, degrees):
        br = self.boundingRect()
        self.setTransformOriginPoint(QtCore.QPointF(br.width() / 2, br.height() / 2))
        self.setRotation(-degrees)
        self.update()



class propBox(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(propBox, self).__init__(parent)

        self.layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

        self.r_label = QtWidgets.QLabel("Rotation:", self)
        self.r_box = QtWidgets.QSpinBox(self)
        self.r_layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.r_layout.addWidget(self.r_label)
        self.r_layout.addWidget(self.r_box)

        self.s_label = QtWidgets.QLabel("Scale:")
        self.s_box = QtWidgets.QSpinBox(self)
        self.s_layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.s_layout.addWidget(self.s_label)
        self.s_layout.addWidget(self.s_box)

        self.layout.addLayout(self.r_layout)
        self.layout.addLayout(self.s_layout)

class mainWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(mainWidget, self).__init__()

        self.layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

        box1 = boxItem(self)
        box1.setRotation(45)
        box2 = boxItem(self)

        self.scene = QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene(self)
        self.scene.setSceneRect(0, 0, 500, 300)
        self.scene.addItem(box1)
        self.scene.addItem(box2)

        self.view = graphicsView(self.scene)

        self.pBox = propBox(self)

        self.layout.addWidget(self.view)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = mainWidget()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Instead of recreating a new prob box, you could create it once and show or hide it depending on the focus.

Comment: @Heike, this won't solve the problem. Instead of an error, the prop box wil be hidden if i try to click on it or its child widget, because the rect graphics item will be out of the focus. I wish i could 'freeze' this focus...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not analyzed because your program crashes so my answer will not focus on it, instead I will focus on the underlying problem.

You just have to have a PropertyBox that you hide or show when necessary. I see a problem trying to use the focusInEvent and focusOutEvent methods because when you press the PropertyBox the item will lose its focus so the PropertyBox itself will be removed (maybe this is the reason for the crash). So instead of using the focus you should use the mousePressEvent and check if there is an item where it was clicked.

Considering the above the solution is:

```py
import random
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class BoxItem(QtWidgets.QGraphicsRectItem):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(BoxItem, self).__init__(QtCore.QRectF(0, 0, 200, 200), parent)

        self.setFlags(
            QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable
            | QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable
            | QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsFocusable
        )
        br = self.boundingRect()
        self.setTransformOriginPoint(
            QtCore.QPointF(br.width() / 2, br.height() / 2)
        )


class PropertyBox(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    rotationChanged = QtCore.Signal(float)
    scaleChanged = QtCore.Signal(float)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(PropertyBox, self).__init__(parent)
        self.m_rotation_spinbox = QtWidgets.QDoubleSpinBox(
            minimum=-360, maximum=360
        )
        self.m_rotation_spinbox.valueChanged.connect(self.rotationChanged)
        self.m_scale_spinbox = QtWidgets.QDoubleSpinBox(
            minimum=0, maximum=100, singleStep=0.1
        )
        self.m_scale_spinbox.valueChanged.connect(self.scaleChanged)

        lay = QtWidgets.QFormLayout(self)
        lay.addRow("Rotation:", self.m_rotation_spinbox)
        lay.addRow("Scale:", self.m_scale_spinbox)

    @property
    def rotation(self):
        return self.m_rotation_spinbox.value()

    @rotation.setter
    def rotation(self, value):
        self.m_rotation_spinbox.setValue(value)

    @property
    def scale(self):
        return self.m_scale_spinbox.value()

    @scale.setter
    def scale(self, value):
        self.m_scale_spinbox.setValue(value)


class GraphicsView(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView):
    currentItemChanged = QtCore.Signal(QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        super(GraphicsView, self).mousePressEvent(event)
        it = self.itemAt(event.pos())
        self.currentItem = it

    @property
    def currentItem(self):
        if not hasattr(self, "_currentItem"):
            self._currentItem = None
        return self._currentItem

    @currentItem.setter
    def currentItem(self, it):
        if self.currentItem != it:
            self._currentItem = it
            self.currentItemChanged.emit(it)


class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent)

        self.m_scene = QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene()
        self.m_view = GraphicsView(self.m_scene)
        self.m_view.currentItemChanged.connect(self.onCurrentItemChanged)

        for i in range(4):
            it = BoxItem()
            self.m_scene.addItem(it)
            it.setPos(QtCore.QPointF(100 * i, 100 * i))
            it.setBrush(QtGui.QColor(*random.sample(range(255), 3)))

        self.m_property_box = PropertyBox()
        self.m_property_box.rotationChanged.connect(self.onRotationChanged)
        self.m_property_box.scaleChanged.connect(self.onScaleChanged)
        self.m_property_box.hide()

        lay = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(self.m_view)
        lay.addWidget(self.m_property_box)

    @QtCore.Slot(QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem)
    def onCurrentItemChanged(self, item):
        self.m_property_box.setVisible(item is not None)
        if item is not None:
            self.m_property_box.rotation = item.rotation()
            self.m_property_box.scale = item.scale()

    @QtCore.Slot(float)
    def onRotationChanged(self, rotation):
        it = self.m_view.currentItem
        if it is not None:
            it.setRotation(rotation)

    @QtCore.Slot(float)
    def onScaleChanged(self, scale):
        it = self.m_view.currentItem
        if it is not None:
            it.setScale(scale)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.resize(640, 480)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: thank you! This is something that i need. Could you tell me why should we use property decorator here. I can't figure out how do they work in a particular case. Especially, QtCore.Slot decorator. 
Thanks.

Comment: @Artem read the docs: [Properties](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#properties) and [pyqtSlot](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/signals_slots.html#the-pyqtslot-decorator). Actually it is not necessary to use both decorators, but a benefit in this case is that it improves the readability using property, and in the case of pyqtSlot has an improvement in performance and memory